# upgrading php 5.1.6 to php 5.2 on plesk 9x?

Tags: php

I want to know how I can upgrade my php using plesk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this using the atomic yum repository before. Instructions for yum are here:
http://www.atomicorp.com/channels/plesk/

To summarize:

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic.sh | sh
sudo yum install php
sudo apachectl graceful # restart Apache for new PHP to be loaded
```

If course you need to be logged in with SSH as root to do this, no easy way that I know to do it from the Plesk interface. But I have done this on a Plesk 9.2 and a Plesk 9.5 installation before.

Edit: added sudo and apache restart in there

Comment: how can i get root access to my server, im using PUTTY!!!

Comment: it says you need to be root to do this

Comment: try adding sudo before each one:

Comment: it says sudo command not found, can i give you accesss to my server pleease this is so important!!

Comment: take a look at the updated code, I added the sudos and also the apache restart which would be needed to load the new PHP copy

Comment: yeh i just did your code, and it says sudo not found!!! :(

Comment: Do you have administrative rights to the server? Try just running "su" and entering the main password for that server, it might or might not work. Otherwise you will have to contact the hosting company that installed Plesk for you on that server and ask them "how to get root access once I'm logged in through SSH using Putty?". Each server is a bit different, but if you're already in with Putty, it's a good start - now you just need to elevate your admin privileges to root and run the above code.

Comment: yes it workeed, thank you very much, i love you man your a genious!!

Comment: is this how i install memcahce aswell!!

Comment: Thanks! For memcache, try using "yum search memcache". From my results doing a "yum install memcached php-pecl-memcache" will install the memcache system and the PHP connections to it. However I don't have experience setting memcached up, so you should find a tutorial that explains it. But the two packages above (and an Apache restart) should allow you to have all the software in place. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Now the atomic repo will directly install php 5.3 by default. So, just had a thought that this will be helpful for someone who is looking to install php 5.2.X from atomic.

```
wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
echo "exclude=php-*5.3*" >> /etc/yum.conf
yum upgrade php
yum -y remove atomic-release*
```